# Disable default notifications android wear

Tags: android, notifications, wear-os

I have an Android Wear App with a `WearableListenerService` that shows a custom notification when it receives a `DataMap`. I have an app on my phone that sends the `DataMap` to wearable app. This app receives notifications from Firebase and the wearable shows them too. I want only Wearable to show my custom notifications not the phone from where it's initiated.

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you. Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/bridger.html):

> By default, notifications are bridged (shared) from an app on a
>   companion phone to the paired watch. If you build a standalone watch
>   app and you have a companion phone app, the apps may duplicate
>   notifications. The Android Wear includes features to handle this
>   problem of duplicate notifications.

You need to add the following to your app's manifest file:

```
<application>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.notificationBridgeMode"
        android:value="NO_BRIDGING" />

</application>
```

Or you can do it in code. See the documentation for more details.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!